# In what context(s) is the Nashville Numbering System preferable to Roman numerals?

Tags: theory, analysis, roman-numerals

In [his answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/88567/21766) to [What's the difference between the Nashville Number system and a Roman Numeral System?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/88566/21766), Dom states that "Roman Numeral Analysis as stated is used mainly in analysis while the Nashville number system is more for practical purposes." He goes on to say that the NNS makes inversions a bit more intuitive (5/7 for a first-inversion V chord, instead of V<sup>6</sup>), but that chromatic chords are easier in Roman numerals.

Based on the above information, the NNS would be best suited for completely diatonic music, which is relatively uncommon in popular music (the repertoire for which the NNS was devised). Furthermore, it seems odd that a main selling point is inversions, when figured bass has worked just fine for centuries.

So in what context(s) would one prefer the NNS over Roman numerals?

Comment: Isn’t diatonic music more common in Nashville than in other centers of pop music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NNS was developed *before the fact*, while RN was developed *after the fact*.

As in, the purpose of NNS is to provide accompaniment in whatever key, to any songs to be recorded that would suit the singer's key, thus saving time re-writing the harmonies.

RN is far more an academic analysis of already existing music, in order to analyse what has already happened - maybe hundreds of years ago, in order to provide exact notation (explanation) of the music.

As far as inversions go, that's not so important in NNS, but is of paramount importance in RN. the two aren't really comparable from a lot of standpoints, although they appear to do similar jobs.

Comment: Are you saying that the NNS is key agnostic, and that writing "1 5 2 4 1" is allows musicians to transpose to any key? If so, how is that different from "I V ii IV I," which is also key agnostic?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "before" and "after" "the fact".

Comment: That aspect is almost the same.  Except RN takes the concept deeper, whereas NNS doesnt, as it doesn't need to, due to its purpose. I've only really given a basic overview as yet.

Comment: @Aaron - RN is examining what is already existing. NNS is more a roadmap of where to go next. No-one has written RN as 'this will happen', rather than 'this is what happened', in comparison to NNS 'this is what will happen'.

Comment: So, NNS is more like standard music notation or chord notation in that it tells one (approximately what to play; whereas RN is an analysis explaining why the music has the effect it has?

Comment: @Aaron - that's my take on it.

Comment: I think you could go farther with this and say that NNS is more appropriate for a modern recording session and RN is more appropriate for a university class. Each part of the music business has its conventions, and even the same area of music will have different conventions in different locations. How you write for musical theatre in NYC has to be different from how you write for folk or country in Nashville which has to be different from how you write for soundtracks in Los Angeles. NNS is one of those conventions.

Comment: @Tim I still don't understand the distinction. How does "2" tell me "what to play" but "ii" doesn't?

Comment: @Richard - they both say the same - except - 2 tells what to play, whereas ii tells what was played. Subtle difference, basically hardly any! In fact, I prefer RN as maj/min are clear(er) as writing '2' still needs that pesky little line to indicate minor. Personally, I've always used a mixture of the two types, for students and myself, mainly for guitar.

Comment: @Richard I think what Tim is saying is that NNS was made and is used for music notation, while RN was made and is used for analysis.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I see now. My confusion is that I've used assignments where I tell students to play "I vi IV V I," so I didn't see the distinction. But it sounds like you're saying that type of exercise is more for the NNS.

Answer (score 1):

I've always believed that the Nashville system was devised to accommodate musicians with little or no ability to read roman numerals or sheet music. Country music has often utilized musicians who can play up a storm, but have little or no formal training and can count from 1 to 10 but had little or no exposure to Roman Numerals. In my own experience both systems have been used interchangeably and I haven't noticed any important difference.